# Azure DevOps yaml: push docker image to different ACRs

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I need to build a docker image in Azure pipeline and push it to different ACRs. I can successfully push an image to the same ACR where it was buid, but when pushing to other ACR the push task fails with "An image does not exist locally with the tag" error.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: REGISTRY1
    repository: $(ACR_URL1)/test
    tags: |
      latest

# This push succeeds
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push to ACR1
  inputs:
    command: push
    containerRegistry: REGISTRY1
    repository: $(ACR_URL1)/test
    tags: |
      latest

# This push fails
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push to ACR2
  inputs:
    command: push
    containerRegistry: REGISTRY2
    repository: $(ACR_URL2)/test
    tags: |
      latest
```

The obvious workaround is to separately build an image on each ACR, but it is far from optimal since the build takes almost an hour. And unfortunately, I cannot use `docker` command line, only DevOps tasks (like `Docker@2`).

Comment: [What about importing image from one ACR to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images) via [azure cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)? Does it sound good?

Comment: Good advice, I tried using this option but failed because we cannot create an Azure subscription Service connection with the necessary permissions. From my local machine using interactive authentication, it does work. So for some people, this may actually be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution happened to be very simple (yet far from obvious). Login to all the ACRs you want to push your image to and do not specify the `containerRegistry` property in the `push` task - it will push the image to all the ACRs you logged in. Example:

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: DEV-ACR

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: TST-ACR

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push to both DEV-ACR and TST-ACR. Note: containerRegistry property is missing!
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    repository: test
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super useful and not at all apparent in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tag the container properly.

Let's say you have two ACRs: `foo.azurecr.io` and `bar.azurecr.io`

Your first step builds the container and tags it as `foo.azurecr.io/test:latest`. You can push that to `foo.azurecr.io` because it's tagged appropriately.

The second push fails because the container isn't tagged as `bar.azurecr.io/test:latest`. You need to tag it. Given your restriction that you can't just run `docker tag` from the command line, you can have a second `build` task. It will only take a few seconds to run because the container is already built.

i.e.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: REGISTRY1
    repository: $(ACR_URL1)/test
    tags: |
      latest

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: REGISTRY2
    repository: $(ACR_URL2)/test
    tags: |
      latest
```

Comment: Could you please provide a YAML example? For the `tag` property I specify the value 'latest'. 'bar.azurecr.io/test' is not a tag, this is part of the repository name/path where I build the image.